# WebStorm debugger breakpoints does not reflected into the browser until re-running the debugger

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, webstorm

My breakpoints set in WebStorm do not work until I hit the 'Rerun' button to restart the debugger. It's a fresh install of the latest WebStorm and Chrome. I have the exact same setup running on my old machine and breakpoints change immediately takes effect without the need to rerun the debugger.

The issue may be related to the communications between WebStorm debugger and the browser. I tried few tricks but could not resolve the problem. Debugging directly in the browser works perfectly fine. I searched the web well and could not find any working solution.

What might cause the problem?

EDIT:
I found some setting that somewhat helps: open the dev-tools in the browser window of the debugger > Network tab > check 'Disable cache'. Now breakpoints can be removed immediately, and only a page refresh is needed in order to make new breakpoints take effect. However, still quite annoying. Any ideas?

Comment: page refresh is usually required to get the breakpoints in code executed on page loading hit. You can try enabling the **Ensure breakpoints are detected when loading scripts** in your run configuration as a workaround. But note that this option may cause degrading of the debugger performance

Comment: tried it (the option is already enabled.) did not changed the behavior

Comment: Same here, I used to debug my Angular application through WebStorm and I loved it. Suddenly, it stopped working. The breakpoints do not break anymore. Furthermore, the attached Console works on page load, but it does not show any `console.log(...)` outputs afterwards